# Customer Error in Asp.net MVC web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

in my MVC web application I need a 404 page for all error. I have editing web.config file which this line:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error redirect="/error/404" statusCode="404" /> 
</customErros>
```

It'work, but in browser url I see URL/error/404. How I can see the called URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `customErrors` node is actually older than `httpErrors` so try this instead. Make sure you have these nodes in your `web.config` as children of the `system.webServer` node:

```
<httpErrors>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/error/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Alternatively you can do this two ways with `customErrors`:
First is to amend the individual `error` node, the second is to change the `customErrors` node. I can't remember if one of these is now obsolete, however feel free to try both.

```
<error statusCode="404" path="/error/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
```

**or**

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
```

If the above aren't working something else would be up. Have you checked the IIS Logs?

**Links**

**[`httpErrors` Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx)**

**[Custom Errors Element documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx)** (Archived)

Comment: Hi, try both solution but without resolve my problem. When i try http://example.com/1234  (and I don't have a route) server respond with a Runtime Error and no redirect error to error/404 route. If i try http://example.com/1234/123 (two parameters) this is intercept by route, pass controller and is redirect to error/404 (becouse there is a Redirect in controller action if not found page) that is a route in Home Controller. Thanks

Comment: I partial solve using Application_error in global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

I partial solve using Application_error in global.asax. I added this method

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            IController controller = new CommonController();

            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");

            var requestContext = new RequestContext(
                 new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);

        }
       }
```

This work fine. The problem is from controller: .i.e. if I don't find a db record, I want return a 404 error with default error page. I want also show in browser the original called url, not the redirect url. Using return View(); in controller, this not happen. How I can solve it? Thanks.